# Disable outputcache programmically before it happens that isn't an exception

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, outputcache

Is there a way to disable the outputcache here programmatically if something happens that is not an exception?

```
  [OutputCache(CacheProfile = "StatisticSheets")]
        public virtual ActionResult GameStatistics(int? eventId, int? divisionId, string ids)
        {
            If(true) {
            // Don't Cache This Page
            }
            return View();
         }
```

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28577455/conditional-cache-using-outputcacheattribute-in-asp-net-mvc-4

Comment: This is a potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380321/how-to-set-remove-attributes-dynamically-in-c

Comment: No has nothing to do with this question @AmoghSarpotdar

Comment: @MikeFlynn : Cant you remove the OutputCache attribute programmatically that is shown in the link above? Check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483124/remove-c-sharp-attribute-of-a-property-dynamically

Answer (score 1):

This is how i have done:

create a derive class from outputcache:

```
public class MyOutputCache : OutputCacheAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // checking route data for special condition
        if(!filterContext.RouteData.Values.TryGetValue("abortcaching",out object _))
        {
            base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

then in controller:

```
    [MyOutputCache(Duration = 60, VaryByParam = "none")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page " + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString();
        
        // it can be your condition
        if (DateTime.Now.Minute %2 == 0) 
        {
            RouteData.Values.Add("abortcaching", "true");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

If you need global to disable then read the below details, at the end also I shared with action method implementation code.

First, we want to capture whether or not the app is in debugging mode when it is launched. We'll store that in a global variable to keep things speedy.

```
public static class GlobalVariables
{
    public static bool IsDebuggingEnabled = false;
}
```

Then in the Global.asax code's Application_Start method, write to the global property.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    SetGlobalVariables();
}

private void SetGlobalVariables()
{
    CompilationSection configSection = (CompilationSection)ConfigurationManager
        .GetSection("system.web/compilation");
    if (configSection?.Debug == true)
    {
        GlobalVariables.IsDebuggingEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

Now we will create our own class to use for caching, which will inherit from `OutputCacheAttribute`.

```
public class DynamicOutputCacheAttribute : OutputCacheAttribute
{
    public DynamicOutputCacheAttribute()
    {
        if (GlobalVariables.IsDebuggingEnabled)
        {
            this.VaryByParam = "*";
            this.Duration = 0;
            this.NoStore = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Now when you decorate your controller endpoints for caching, simply use your new attribute instead of `[OutputCache]`.

```
// you can use CacheProfiles or manually pass in the arguments, it doesn't matter.
// either way, no caching will take place if the app was launched with debugging
[DynamicOutputCache(CacheProfile = "Month")]
public ViewResult contact()
{
    return View();
}
```

With Action Method

-> For .net Framework: `[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]`

-> For .net Core: `[ResponseCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]`

You can use the particular action method above way

Comment: So I didn't want a global disable of it. How do you do it within the actual action.

Comment: All action method or selected action method?

Comment: -> For .net Framework: [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)] 
-> For .net Core: [ResponseCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]

You can use the particular action method above way

Comment: Man are you not reading the question.  I want it dynamic. You are statically defining now on the attribute.